# How to display the images from MySQL database in Android using JSON object

Tags: android, database, json, string, image

I've been trying several ways of displaying my JSON images but my solutions never succeeded.

I've parsed my JSON and I'm getting the response.

However included the response is an image which I need to display in my application.

Recieving the image as :"img src=question/images/u2_1_l2_q66" which is just string. I'm getting the same text as in emulator **"not a image"**.

In drawable, should I add the image ?

How can I display these image in my application ? Please guide me.

Any help would be appreciable.

> code

```
       protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tid", tid));
        json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_quesurl, "GET", params);
        Log.d("All Groups: ", json.toString());
        try {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            System.out.println("Success");
            groups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUP);
            System.out.println("Result Success+++"+groups);
             for (int i = 0; i < groups.length();i++) {
            JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);
            String question = c.getString(TAG_QUES);
            System.out.println("Checking ::"+question);
            ques1.add(question);
            String img = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
            System.out.println("Checking ::"+img);
            imgarr.add(img);
             }
        } else {
            showAlert();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        System.out.println("Error "+e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        ques1=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(ques1));
        imgarr=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(imgarr));
        TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
        txtque.setText("Q" + num + ")" + ques1.get(j) + imgarr.get(g));
           }
```

> php code

```
      $group[$i]['image']= base64_encode(file_get_contents("http://10.0.2.2/question/images/".$row['image']));                                                                                                     
        $i++;
      array_push($response["group"], $group);
```

Comment: What you getting in the tag TAG_IMAGE?

Comment: Change your image in php to base64 and then decode it in image in android.I can give you the code

Comment: @kumarandroid in TAG_IMAGE only im getting like this "img src=question/images/u2_1_l2_q66"

Comment: @sammarjaved i can't understand can explain it....

Comment: Please guide me to fix my problem..

Comment: In database for image i have given the path for the image for each question like this "img src=question/images/u2_1_l2_q66" How to display the image in emulator..I want to add these images folder to drawables please help me..

Comment: @kumar_android please help me. really i don't know to solve my problem..

Comment: you have to parse the response of the tag and get u2_1_l2_q66, image name and set it in a imageview by using drawable.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","sarwar");
mysql_select_db("ess");
$sql=mysql_query("select image from default_products ");

$i=0;

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{   




//Where Image Exists.
//First taking path from database and then image from folder against that path and then //converting it ino base64 and then Json
   $output[$i]['image']= base64_encode(file_get_contents("http://ur ip address/ess/uploads/default/products/".$row['image']));



  $i++;
}


print(json_encode($output));




mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: this is php code first apply it according to your database and folder names

Answer (score 1):

```
String image;
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {



                try{
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("//Ur URL");

                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                         is = entity.getContent();
                }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                }

                try{
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        is.close();

                        result=sb.toString();
                }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                }
                return null;
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
                  try{


                        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                      for(int i=0;i<=jArray.length();i++)
                      {
                                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                            String  image=json_data.getString("image");








                      }

             byte[] rawImage = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
                                                  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawImage, 0, rawImage.length); 



                                                  imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);


                }

                catch(JSONException e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                }

            }
```

Comment: this will show only one image if you want to show all images coming from MySQL then Create Image View at run time inside the for loop.and put code above the catch block inside for loop